# Css - Mobile posistion fixed , definitive solution

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, css-position

i got problem with this **on mobile**:

```
<div class="sticky">sticky to bottom</div>

.sticky{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
```

on desktop it is clear good, on mobile (i only tested up on android, but i guess also on iOS), while scrolling the page, it doesn't remains sticked to the bottom of the window, but it scrolls up togheter with the document.

So, i searched trough stack and google, and found many solutions, iScroll.js, Scrollability, webkit tricks , and so on.

Is there anyone who can give me the better solution in terms of performance (i don't want to include huge files in my pages)?

Thanks.

Actually i'm trying with this code:

```
$(window).on('scrollstart',function(){
    $('.sticky').css('top','100%').fadeOut();
  });
  $(window).on('scrollstop',function(){
    $('.sticky').css('top','100%').fadeIn();
  });

(function(){

  var special = jQuery.event.special,
  uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
  uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

  special.scrollstart = {
    setup: function() {

      var timer,
      handler =  function(evt) {

        var _self = this,
        _args = arguments;

        if (timer) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
        } else {
          evt.type = 'scrollstart';
          jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
        }

        timer = setTimeout( function(){
          timer = null;
        }, special.scrollstop.latency);

      };

      jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid1, handler);

    },
    teardown: function(){
      jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid1) );
    }
  };

  special.scrollstop = {
    latency: 300,
    setup: function() {

      var timer,
      handler = function(evt) {

        var _self = this,
        _args = arguments;

        if (timer) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        timer = setTimeout( function(){

          timer = null;
          evt.type = 'scrollstop';
          jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);

        }, special.scrollstop.latency);

      };

      jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid2, handler);

    },
    teardown: function() {
      jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid2) );
    }
  };

})();
```

Comment: This is caused by the browser not sending scroll events while your finger is down, and you can't really do much about it without large javascript libraries AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already had this problem, just like you many solutions are not good for me then I use this technique to seem good for the user :

Detect with Javascript if you scroll and then hide the block until the scroll is stoped and show it again.

Comment: i'm testing it out, but what about  scrolling , i red touch devices doesn't fires the scroll until it stops :/ !?

Comment: you can use this events : scrollstart and scrollstop to detect if the scrolling is stoped :)

Comment: oh this is nice, i will tell you about this, if no other good answer i'll accept this (if it works ehehe)

Comment: @katch check i updated my question, the problem perxists, i tryed like you told me but when scrollstop the page return on top showing the sticky element and it doesn't remains on same window y position, unbelievable lol

Comment: you must change with .hide() and .show(), not fadeOut() and fadeIn() because it takes time ;)

Comment: really doesn't fixed yet, also tryed :(